# Edit review, what does "Template is in use!" mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, error-message

Reviewing edits this afternoon, I got this:

> [image: Freehand Pumpkin]

I'm fairly sure the "Template in use!" I have not seen before.

What does it mean?

Comment: +1 for a beautiful bow on your freehand red circle. Oh, and for reporting something that probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Bart, when I Pig's Ear the circle, I like to make it something else. It was a marrow this time (those are *leaves*, but thanks anyway).

Comment: I'm sure Oded will soon tell you that it's a bug with the localization changes :)

Comment: No comment, @slhck

Comment: @Oded nice comment ;)

Comment: Localisation. It's always localisation...

Comment: Is that a new way of spelling caching, @michaelb958?

Comment: Well, now it's oscillation. :)

Comment: @Pops Well, it seems to be breaking lots of things these days...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**So it works!**

Ahem, it was just some test code that I forgot to remove.

That message is relatively hard to generate natively for a number of reasons. I needed to make sure I was editing the right template.

A fix will be out in the next deploy.

Fortunately I didn't use swearwords or my CC number in that occasion...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to help out testing :-)